# Error during Android 64-bit Delphi app deployment

Tags: android, 64-bit, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm trying to build a 64-bit android app in Delphi 10.3.3, I get this error during deployment : `[PAClient Error] Error: E6409 Cannot open file "D:\...\Android64\Release\TestApp\linked_res.ap_". The system cannot find the file specified`

I don't have any file with name linked_res in deployment, I've built the project twice. Why I'm get this error?

Comment: hi @androidcode, I have the same problem, did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

go to Deployment ( Project->Deployment ) and add "provider_paths.xml" file and set "remote path" to "res\xml"